# Attractive force integral between a rod and a point charge

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

A thin, homogeneous rod of length $l$ has the charge density $q$ (charge per length unit). The force between two point charges $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ at distance $r$ is equal to:

$$k\frac{Q_1Q_2}{r^2}$$

**A)** Calculate the force by which the rod attracts a charge Q of opposite sign, located at a distance $a$ from the end of the rod.

**B)** How large is the attractive force if we instead place the charge $Q$ in a normal plane through the rods center point at distance $\frac{l}{2}$ from the rod?

**Attempted solution:**

**A)**

First, we draw an image of the situation:

[image]

We put down a coordinate system with 0 at the left end of the rod. The rod is of length $l$ and then there is another distance $a$ to the point charge.

Let us divide the rod into very small segments that we call $dx$.

Then we create an expression for $dF$ where $q$ is the charge of the rod:

$$dF = \frac{Qq}{(L+a-x)^2} dx$$

The force then becomes:

$$F = \int_a^l \frac{kQq}{(L+a-x)^2} dx = \Big[ \frac{kQq}{L+a-x} \Big]_0^l = \frac{kQql}{a(a+l)}$$

**B)**

Here I am not sure I understand the setup. Is the point charge located "above" the center of the rod? Similar to the location of the letters "dx" in the image above? Over what would be integrated? It does not seem to be a one-dimensional problem?

The expected answer is:

$$\frac{k2\sqrt{2}Qq}{l}$$

The appearance of the square root of 2 leads me into thinking that there are some trigonometric things going on.

Any suggestions for how to finish this question off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Due to symmetry, the net attractive force is along the vertical direction. Then,

$$dF =\frac{kQq\cos\theta}{r^2}dx
= \frac{kQq\frac L2}{(\frac{L^2}4+x)^{3/2}} dx$$

and the total force below can be integrated with the substitution $t= \frac{2x}L$,

$$F = \int_{-\frac L2}^{\frac L2} \frac{kQq\frac L2}{(\frac{L^2}4+x)^{3/2}} dx
=\frac{2kQq}L \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dt}{(1+t^2)^{3/2}}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}kQq}L$$

Answer (score 0):

The plane normal (= perpendicular) to the axis of symmetry of the rod through the center of the rod is also the set of points each of which is the same distance from the center of each end of the rod.  Rotating the rod around its axis of symmetry leaves the rod in the same location and orientation.  The same rotation does the same thing to the plane.  (In fact every plane perpendicular to the symmetry axis of the rod lands exactly on itself throughout such a rotation.)

[image: Setting]

You can treat this as an integral on the interval $[-\ell/2, \ell/2]$.  A significant simplification comes from using symmetry to match contributions from the left and right halves having the same $r$ since the horizontal components of their two attraction vectors cancel, leaving only a vertical resultant.  Nevertheless, this resultant vector's vertical component is written using at least one trigonometric function (but you should be used to using trigonometry to extract vertical and horizontal components of vectors by now).